# Is there any advantage in doing unit testing along with acceptance testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose you are building an API in Rails. Is it enough if we write request specs alone without the model specs, controller specs and the view specs? Why do we need unit testing if we do acceptance and functional testing or feature testing for front end web projects. I insisted on doing unit testing as it allows you to write decoupled code but my colleague is against it. What are the best practices on this in the ruby on rails community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have time to do one type of testing, and you are writing an API, then it might make sense to only do feature testing by simply calling your API endpoints. After all, it's pretty important that those endpoints return the expected results.

However, when your feature tests start breaking, you will potentially have a terrible time figuring out the source of the problems without unit tests. Is there a core piece of your software that most of your endpoints are using? Good luck refactoring that without a robust set of unit tests.

But that really speaks to what you have to figure out -- is your core set pretty stable? Are you really just adding features or new endpoints? If so, you can probably get away with a heavy feature test approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rails and testing go together like peas and carrots.  [Here is a great](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) resource that highlights (better than I ever could) the importance of using tests (of all degrees) in your Rails projects.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "the community", but in my opinion it depends on the complexity of the project. If it's a very straightforward API project, doing only feature tests may be fine.

But if the project becomes larger, unit tests allow you to better pinpoint errors in case anything breaks. I.e. you don't see "there's a bug somewhere in feature X" but "this or that class does not work when invoking a particular method with specific arguments".